# Number of executed test case more than total number of test case

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-mocha

on running unit test cases using karma. The output displays the total number of executed more than the total number of unit tests. How can the number of executed test case be more than total test case?

[image]

Comment: In your scenario, apparently.

Comment: I mean how it's possible. what' the possible cause.